# google-auth-library import issues with vite react project

Tags: vite, google-auth-library

I setup a brand new react project using vite and added the google-auth-library package via yarn.
When I import JWTAccess from the google-auth-library, I'm getting an [this TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJrra.png). When looking into the stack trace, I notice that I'm getting

> Could not load content for http://localhost/node_modules/agent-base/src/index.ts (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)

Not sure what I'm missing here?

I tried to delete the node_modules and reinstall and I tried to install the packages that have this error individually.